# Simulating click event in SSRS Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, reporting-services

In an SSRS report I have a button that the user can click to activate a job on the server. This then make visible a textbox and image to show data is busy loading. On the textbox placeholder I have added html code in the hope that I can simulate a button click - the action on this button will wait 5 minutes and refresh the page.

[image]

My JavaScript is not kicking off the click event - which is frustrating.

My code:

```html
=iif(Parameters!RunSSRS.Value, "<button id=""btn1"" onclick=""addClick()"">Job is busy running...</button>
    <script type=""text/javascript"">
        function clickButton() {
            document.querySelector('#btn1').click();
        }
    </script>","")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your workflow looks like but I have done lots of these kind of reports where I have a report that kicks off a job (say a long running SSIS task) and then a linked report that monitors the job. The "monitor" report has the `AutoRefresh` set to a specific value, say 30 seconds, so that users can see when the job is complete. This might be an alternative route for you.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Might need to rethink this. Would've been great if the autorefresh had the ability to have conditions against them.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling the addClick() function when the button is clicked, but there is no such function defined. Instead, you should call the clickButton() function, which contains the code to simulate a button click.

```
=iif(Parameters!RunSSRS.Value, "<button id=""btn1"" onclick=""clickButton()"">Job is busy running...</button>
    <script type=""text/javascript"">
        function clickButton() {
            document.querySelector('#btn1').click();
        }
    </script>","")
```

Comment: Hi Ricky, apologies. did correct the onclick but the button still isn't clicked when the textbox becomes visible. Any ideas? I have code in the action part of the place holder - so would expect that to kick off

Comment: I think it could be because that function wasn't in the dom from the start, can you put that script tag in the HEAD tag or at the top of body and make it load all the time and try again